# Fixed CSS Div overlaps other box

Tags: html, css, fixed

I'm not really a CSS-hero ;-) Well, I try to create a form with bootstrap and some custom css.

I want 3 columns:

1. Content
2. Editor
3. Settings

The **Editor** should be fixed.

Thats my html: http://d.pr/n/YsVJ

The part of the fixed editor is:

`<div class="form-vertical fixed">
<?php echo $this->form->getControlGroup('content'); ?>
</div>`

I added some custom css like this:

http://d.pr/n/v9EN

Well, it works, the editor is fixed, but there is one problem: If I use my iPad or Netbook the div of the editor overlaps the div of the settings (span3).

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting something as fixed it removes it from the flow of the document, which means it won't affect anything else on the page.

You would need to use a margin or padding to create a bit of extra space for the element that is being overlapped and not positioned fixed.

Comment: So I have to add margin or padding to the fixed div or to the non-fixed divs?

Comment: The non-fixed div. You're basically creating a blank space for the fixed div to sit in